# OnPaint leaves trails when resizing

Tags: c#, winforms

I am creating a form with custom border.
I wanted to draw my own border using onPaint override.
Unfortunately, I get trails of image when I just use the below code.

Does anyone know how to fix this?
And yes, I have set the DoubleBuffered to true.

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
  Graphics g = e.Graphics;

  // Background
  g.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#EFEFF7")), new Rectangle(0, 0, this.Width - 1, this.Height - 1));

  // Outer Borders
  g.DrawImage(Resources.Resource.OuterBorderTopLeft, new Rectangle(0, 0, 13, 13));
  g.DrawImage(Resources.Resource.OuterBorderTopLeft1, new Rectangle(13, 0, 221, 13));
  g.DrawImage(Resources.Resource.OuterBorderTopLeft2, new Rectangle(0, 13, 13, 221));
  g.DrawImage(Resources.Resource.OuterBorderTopRight, new Rectangle(this.Size.Width - 13, 0, 13, 13));
  g.DrawImage(Resources.Resource.OuterBorderTopRight1, new Rectangle(this.Size.Width - 13, 13, 13, 221));
  g.DrawImage(Resources.Resource.OuterBorderTopRight2, new Rectangle(this.Size.Width - 234, 0, 221, 13));
  g.DrawImage(Resources.Resource.OuterBorderBottomLeft, new Rectangle(0, this.Size.Height - 13, 13, 13));
  g.DrawImage(Resources.Resource.OuterBorderBottomLeft1, new Rectangle(0, this.Size.Height - 234, 13, 221));
  g.DrawImage(Resources.Resource.OuterBorderBottomLeft2, new Rectangle(13, this.Size.Height - 13, 221, 13));
  g.DrawImage(Resources.Resource.OuterBorderBottomRight, new Rectangle(this.Size.Width - 13, this.Size.Height - 13, 13, 13));
  g.DrawImage(Resources.Resource.OuterBorderBottomRight1, new Rectangle(this.Size.Width - 234, this.Size.Height - 13, 221, 13));
  g.DrawImage(Resources.Resource.OuterBorderBottomRight2, new Rectangle(this.Size.Width - 13, this.Size.Height - 234, 13, 221));
  base.OnPaint(e);
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try overriding the resize method, too:

```
protected override void OnResize(EventArgs e) {
  base.OnResize(e);
  this.Invalidate();
}
```

or in the constructor, you can add another setting:

```
public Form1() {
  InitializeComponent();
  this.DoubleBuffered = true;
  this.ResizeRedraw = true;
}
```

Comment: Although optional, I recommend setting this.DoubleBuffered = true. Else, the flickering will be something fierce.